# Solving a system of 4 equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, rational-functions

why gives me that system of equations:

$-\tfrac{1}{x} +2ux =0$

$-\tfrac{1}{y}+2uy=0$

$1+2uz=0$

a)--> $x^2 = y^2= -z $ ?

And using the equation: $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1$ gives b)$z = 1 (+,-) \sqrt{2}$

I dont understand  a) --> and from a) to b)

Would be great, if someone could explain

Comment: If $x^2=y^2=-z$ then one has to be complex which isnt you are mistajen somewhere

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong. I used the equations you gave
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
2 u x-\frac{1}{x}&=0\\
2 u y-\frac{1}{y}&=0\\
2 u z &=-1\\
x^2+y^2+z^2 &=1
\end{cases}
\end{align}
whose solution are
\begin{align}
(x,y,z,u)=
\begin{cases}
\left(x , + x , -x^2 , 1+\frac{x^2}{2}  \right)\\
\left(x , - x , -x^2 , 1+\frac{x^2}{2}  \right)
\end{cases}
\end{align}
where $x^4 = 3-2\sqrt{2} \implies x = \left\{ -\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1},\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1},-i \sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}},i \sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}\right\}$.

The 8 points above are the solutions of your system.

I don't know what you wanted to know. Please, rephrase your question so we can better help you.

Comment: equation 4 is wrong: $y^2$ instead of $x^2$ --> this is an example of a optimization book. (u must be positive).

Comment: ok. I rewrote it.